# Как вызвать контроллер в виджете Yii2?

Tags: yii2

хочу добавить в виджет свой контроллер и не понимаю как. Прошу помочь.
расположение виджета в папке: **app/components/Filter**
расположение контроллера в папке: **app/components/Filter/controllers/FilterController.php** (namespace app\components\Filter\controllers;)
нужный action в контроллере: **actionSelectVars**

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
...
'rules' => [
...
'filter/select-vars' => 'components/Filter/filter/select-vars'
...
```

пытаюсь вызвать action по адресу **site.ru/filter/select-vars** и получаю ошибку-страница не найдена. Где ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

У каждого свое место должно быть. Модели в /models, контроллеры в /controllers должны быть расположены. site.ru/filter/select-vars отправляет запрос к методу actionSelectVars, контроллера FilterController и располагаться этот контроллер должен по умолчанию рядом с SiteController.

Yii2 фреймворк пока еще не настолько умный, что может найти контроллер из любого места. [Перечитать документацию о контроллерах](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-controllers).

И виджеты более правильно все таки располагать в директории /app/widgets, у каждого ведь свое место должно быть.

Comment: /app/widgets согласен...
но всетаки, если способ достучаться до контроллера именно в папке виджета? может я неправильно написал правило rule в urlManager? я ведь явно указываю где искать

Comment: Нет, не явно. Путь к файлу контроллера и путь в урлменеджере это очень разные вещи. Перечитай еще раз о роутах и все станет ясно.